# Ceph Cluster down

Tags: cluster-computing, ceph, proxmox

I have a cluster with three Ceph nodes.  The cluster was working fine, until we move one host to other physical location, since it we have the third node down, alwaya said OSD/MON down, and degraded data redundancy objects.

Comment: try serverfault.com  , and please read [tour]

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is that the network connection is exactly the same for the nodes. Ceph doesn't like change of network settings.

Comment: This is still true. Especially changing IP addresses of monitors is to be handled with explicit care.